# Windows API and SendMessage()

Tags: windows, winapi

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;

y = y << 16;
int coord = x | y;

NativeMethods.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(coord));
NativeMethods.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(coord));
```

Using the above code (ref: MSDN), I'm able to select a row in a datagridview in an external application. I would like to know how I can send a ctrl-a and ctrl-c to the same datagridview.

Still trying to connect to why the x and y variables are initialized to 5,10, and why y is left shifted by 16 and then | with x.

Comment: Are you hooking this "external" app? Or do you have all the source code?

Comment: referencing an external Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
SendMessage( hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CTRL, 0 );
SendMessage( hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x43, 0 );
// Ctrl and C keys are both pressed.
SendMessage( hwnd, WM_KEYUP, 0x43, 0 );
SendMessage( hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_CTRL, 0 );
```

`0x43` being the C key (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx)

---

**Edit:** If it doesn't work, try sending [`WM_COPY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649022(VS.85).aspx), which should be a better idea.

```
SendMessage( hwnd, WM_COPY, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: No luck. I tried the following 

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_CTRL), new IntPtr(0)); SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x43), new IntPtr(0)); SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x43), new IntPtr(0)); SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_CTRL), new IntPtr(0)); 

I can see the row selected, but when I do a ctrl-v in notepad, I don't see the text copied

Comment: I edited my answer, I've just came across `WM_COPY` on MSDN, try that.

Comment: WM_Copy did not work. 

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPY, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0))

Answer (score 1):

You might actually need [**Windows Subclassing**](http://www.aaronballman.com/programming/REALbasic/WindowSubclassingArticle.php). Note this is not C++ Subclassing.

This technique sends messages from a particular Window Procedure (WndProc) to another WndProc, thus achieving what you seem to want.

Once setup it just works. MSDN is light on this information, thus the link above as a tutorial.

More info:

[Subclassing Controls - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[ActiveX Controls: Subclassing a Windows Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268967%28VS.60%29.aspx)

** [Subclassing Windows Forms Controls](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Subclassing-Windows-Forms-Controls/) May be the most pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Links for "Windows Hooking." It's a technique to hook or trap messages and events in external applications.

[Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)

[EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)

[MSDN Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx) Good overview.

HTH